# Find out if two curves are parallel in c++

Tags: algorithm

I'm working with a very hard problem (at least for me), concerning parallelism of two curves.
I have an array of objects called CPolyline that has an array of 2d-points, defined as follow:

```
class CPoint2D
{
  //...
  double m_dX;
  double m_dY;
};
typedef CArray<CPoint2D, CPoint2D> CArrayPoint2D;
class CPolyline
{
  //...
  CArrayPoint2D m_aPnts;
};
typedef CArray<CPolyline *, CPolyline *> CArrayPPolyline
```

Defined as described, it would be analythically pretty easy to find if two elements of this array are parallel, sampling points along the polylines and rounding up the slope.
Now, knowing which polylines I have to compare, comes the big trouble, because this method works only under the condition that the two curves have both same starting and ending point, condition never verified in my case. I should find a point (X0,Y0) of start and a point (X1,Y1) of end where I can evaluate the slope of my curves.
This can seems a pretty easy task, but it requires a lot, too many, ifs because, if we consider this two basic (particular cases) examples, where +s are polyline points and °s define the lenght o interest:

```
+-°----------+      <-Line1
  +----------°--+   <-Line2

Line 1->+
        ° +
        | |<-Line 2
        | |
        | |
        | |
        + °
          +
```

we see that they requires two ifs.
Moreover, if we consider two hyperboles (hard to draw, sorry) the situation gets hot:

```
+----°-+    <- Line 1
|+---+      <- Line 2
||
|+-----°--+
+------+
```

Knowing and hopefully understanding all this garbage, is there a fast way to find out my lenghts of interest?
Oh, I almost forget: have to be fast.

Comment: Define what you mean by "parallel".  Mathematically, "parallel" is only unambiguously defined for Lines.  It is not formally defined for either line segments or polylines, so you need to tell us what you mean.

Comment: Assuming that this is what you mean by parallel, why can't you take every two consecutive points in both arrays, construct two lines, and ensure that their slopes are equal.

Comment: I can't scratch here so I assume I'm not so clear. Yes: mathematically parallel is unambiguosly defined. My polylines here come from an automatic vectorization of a photo, so they are not straight lines, but curves. I have to find if two lines are close to be parallel, if m1 (slopes of poly[i]), m2 (slope of poly[j]), sampled along the curve, are m1~m2. I'll try to upload some screenshot maybe.